# For academic tenure applications, is the number of first-author publications or the number of total publications more important?

Tags: job, faculty-application, tenure-track

I'm an academic in the fields of biomaterials and biochemistry, willing to apply for academic tenure positions.

Unfortunately, I don't have a high number of publications, but they are either first-author publications in (good or average) journals or equal first-author publications.

I have coworkers who published 30 or more papers, but the number of first-author publications that they have is lower than mine.

What are my chances of landing a position in a "decent" university? Do employers really care much about the first-authorship these days?

Comment: "_Willing_ to apply"? If you don't want to, don't. There are plenty of candidates "eager to apply". Altogether, somehow the tone of your question seems to indicate that you are significantly clueless about the whole business. Do you have an advisor/mentor/senior who can explain to you how things work?

Comment: I can understand that academic applications go through an academic committee and there are many aspects to discuss in these applications. All I'm trying to ask is, say that I and one of my coworkers, who graduated from the same school and department and who got postdoc in the same institute, apply for the same position, but he/she has 30 papers where, say, only 4 of them are first-author publications, on the other hand I have 8, but all are first-author publications. Do committees really look at the quality of the publications, or is what stands out is a huge list of publications?

Comment: This is going to be closed as too broad, opinion based, and based on individual preferences.  The best way to find a useful answer is to read the CVs of faculty who were recently hired at departments that you would like to work for.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your record is what it is. So a theoretical answer is of little use to you now, unless you have time to change things.

I'd recommend that you apply for positions that you find interesting, and make your application as positive as you can. There is, in most fields, an advantage in collaborative work, especially for a junior faculty member.

In general, people look for a variety of things that indicate a successful future. It isn't just a game of counting papers. Good papers are better than mediocre ones. Lead authorship is better than simple acknowledgement. More is better than less. But a well rounded picture is best.

But in your applications, aim for a wider rather than narrower range of reputation of the universities. You won't know until you put yourself into the mix. But show that you are still active and have ideas for future research. It isn't just the past that is important, but people's judgement about your future. Use letters of recommendation to push that idea.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on disciplines, but normally people want to see that you can yourself write, but also that you can collaborate, and that you know what it's like to write a strong paper / publish in the top venue. How many papers it takes to communicate this varies by discipline and person.  Note also that in some disciplines having a single male author anywhere on an author list, means that paper won't contribute to a woman's chances of getting tenure. I wouldn't be surprised if similar effects held for minorities' names vs whatever the locally dominant demographic was. https://scholar.harvard.edu/sarsons/publications/note-gender-differences-recognition-group-work

Comment: Actually, this follow up clarifies that article  https://scholar.harvard.edu/sarsons/publications/note-gender-differences-recognition-group-work